# Record Update triggers Process Builder, but Platform Event Action Doesn't Occur

Tags: process-builder, connected-apps, debugging, platform-event

In a sandbox, [process builder](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/apn/connecting-aws-and-salesforce-enables-enterprises-to-do-more-with-customer-data/) is triggering a platform event on record updates.
[image]
[image]

When I update the record, I am not seeing my platform event in the [debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_debug.htm) or in SF [workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IEgtQAG).

To confirm the process was firing, I have added a chatter post action to the process as well to confirm the process is firing.

Which it is, this is not only confirmed by the chatter post but also in the debug logs for flows.

Why is my platform event not being processed?

This is following: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/apn/connecting-aws-and-salesforce-enables-enterprises-to-do-more-with-customer-data/

Comment: Can you show us the filter logic in the light blue diamond node?  Also, are you checking everytime the Opportunity is created, or also edited?

Comment: No conditions just execute any time the opp is created or editing. This process is confirmed to be triggering by the chatter post / the debug logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Platform event was triggering. It was not present in logs as I thought it would be.

Narender Singh on https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eWWGQA2
Suggested I create a process for the event to confirm it fired on the PE event.

Following this - I confirmed the event fired.
https://unofficialsf.com/creating-a-custom-notification-flow-that-responds-to-a-platform-event/